# "Что" в роли связки

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Имеем предложение:
***Семья без детей (?) что цветок без запаха.***

Очень давно с такими примерами не сталкивалась, поэтому не могу толком вспомнить, что здесь со знаками. И правило тоже найти, к сожалению, не могу.
Здесь должно стоять тире, как в варианте со "значит", или вообще ничего? Помогите, пожалуйста, освежить это правило в памяти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) **Семья без детей что цветок без запаха.**

(2) **Семья без детЕй — что цветок без запаха.**

При наличии паузы ставим тире (этот вариант предпочтительнее).

**Правило:**

Тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым не ставится:

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106

5. Если сказуемое выражено оборотом со сравнительными частицами **как, словно, что, точно, вроде как и др.**: Жизнь как легенда; Небо словно раскинутый шатер; Брошка вроде как пчелка (Ч.); Лес точно сказка; **Неделя что один день.** Быстро проходит; Пруд как блестящая сталь (Фет).

**Примечание.** **При акцентировании сказуемого** (обычно в стилистических целях) **тире возможно:**  Чернеющие прогалины — как черные острова в белом снежном море (Бун.);

Comment: Странно, но Кузнецов все сравнения с **что** даёт с запятыми: **_Глаза, что звёзды._** *Глуп, что пень. Брюзжишь, что осенняя муха.* и т.п.

Comment: Глуп, что пень. Брюзжишь, что осенняя муха.  Это предложения со сравнительными оборотами. А вот "Глаза, что звёзды" как отдельное предложение  не должно писаться с запятой.

Comment: Спасибо, я согласен с Вами. Но с этим правилом страшный бардак, похоже. Я посмотрел в поиске несколько пословиц ("ласковое слово что весенний день" и т.п.) — чаще они без запятой или с тире, но иногда с запятой, причём даже в солидных изданиях. Никогда бы не подумал.

Comment: Может, традиционное написание (еще до Правил 1956 года).

Comment: А это новое правило? Тогда да, наверное. Словари Ушакова и Даля дают с запятыми; Ефремова не приводит примеров; Ожегов приводит те же примеры, что и Кузнецов, кроме ошибочного. Может, как-то связаться с редколлегией словаря Кузнецова или как-то по-другому обратить на это внимание? Должно же это когда-то закончиться?

Comment: У Кузнецова найдется для Вас объяснение, он скажет, что это назывное предложение: Глаза, как звезды, губы, что коралл... https://poembook.ru/poem/1346832

Comment: @Jasmin,  в предложении "Глаза(,),что звезды" вы не усматриваете сравниния?

Comment: Это или сказуемое в двусоставном предложении (чаще всего), или сравнение в назывном предложении: Но грамматика должна соответствовать тексту, то есть быть понятной.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь *что* — сравнительный союз (разговорный), по значению сходный со словами *как будто, словно*. Перед ним можно либо ничего не ставить, так как после него — именная часть составного сказуемого, либо использовать тире (если хотите сделать сравнение эмоциональным). См. примеры:

> Плачет она [русалка], братцы мои, глаза волосами утирает, а волоса у нее зеленые, **что** твоя конопля. *Тургенев, Бежин луг.*
>
> В полдень дождь перестал,
>   И, **что** белый пушок,
>   На осеннюю грязь
>   Начал падать снежок.
>   *И. Никитин, Встреча зимы.*

Таким образом, правильно:

> Семья без детей (или —) что цветок без запаха.